# How can I clear a value during inline edit in a lightning datatable?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have a datatable LWC where I have implemented inline editing.  It behaves like every field is required and displays "Complete this field." if I try and delete the contents of any field.  These fields are not required in the Sobject.

Is there a way to change this behavior?

HTML

```
<template>
<template if:false={showSpinner}>
    <lightning-datatable
        data={mydata}
        columns={columns}
        key-field={keyField}
        sorted-by={sortedBy}
        sorted-direction={sortedDirection}
        max-row-selection={maxRowSelection}
        selected-rows={selectedRows}
        hide-checkbox-column={hideCheckboxColumn}
        suppress-bottom-bar={suppressBottomBar}
        onsort={updateColumnSorting}
        onsave={handleSave}
        oncancel={cancelChanges}
        onrowselection={handleRowSelection}
        onrowaction={handleRowAction}>
    </lightning-datatable>
</template>
<template if:true={showSpinner}>
    <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="medium"></lightning-spinner>
</template>
```

JS

```
    handleSave(event) {
    // Only used with inline editing
    const draftValues = event.detail.draftValues;

    // apply drafts to mydata
    let data = [...this.mydata];
    data = data.map(item => {
        const draft = draftValues.find(d => d[this.keyField] == item[this.keyField]);
        if (draft != undefined) {
            let fieldNames = Object.keys(draft);
            fieldNames.forEach(el => item[el] = draft[el]);
        }
        return item;
    });

    // apply drafts to outputData
    let odata = [...this.outputData];
    odata = odata.map(oitem => {
        const odraft = draftValues.find(d => d[this.keyField] == oitem[this.keyField]);
        if (odraft != undefined) {
            let ofieldNames = Object.keys(odraft);
            ofieldNames.forEach(el => oitem[el] = odraft[el]);
        }
        return oitem;
    });  

    this.outputEditedRows = [...odata]; // Set output attribute values
    console.log('this.outputEditedRows',this.outputEditedRows);
    this.savePreEditData = [...data];   // Resave the current table values
    this.mydata = [...data];            // Reset the current table values

    // Force clearing of the edit highlights
    this.columns = [...this.columns];
}

cancelChanges(event) {
    // Only used with inline editing
    this.mydata = [...this.savePreEditData];
}
```

[image: Error when trying to clear any field:]

Comment: Could you please share some code and add more details about what is tried and where you are facing issue 

Comment: Where are you setting the "columns" variable?

Comment: Columns are being set in Apex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I was having this issue is that in my column attributes, I had defined typeAttributes = ''

Changing this to typeAttributes = null no longer requires a field to have a value when editing.